# MS Access - change colors of the bar chart based on series value

Tags: ms-access, charts, vba, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to write a code in MS Access 2013 that will change the color of the each bar in the chart based on value of the series. Data are stored in query that changes according to the set of conditions.

In the form is chain of combo boxes and listboxes witch set the conditions for query. After requery the output is a graph.

```
Private Sub listS_AfterUpdate()

Me.graph.Requery

Dim i

With graph

        For i = 1 To .SeriesCollection.Count

           If .SeriesCollection(i).Value < 0.78 Then

            .SeriesCollection(i).Border.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            .SeriesCollection(i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
           Else

            .SeriesCollection(i).Border.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            .SeriesCollection(i).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
          End If
        Next i
 End With
 End Sub
```

The problem lies in the `IF` statement:

```
If .SeriesCollection(i).Value < 0.78 Then
```

Error:

> Object doesn't support this property or method

Can anyone help me out with this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've done this in Excel, but the way I had to do it was to have multiple ranges in the bar chart, each with a different color, and then the data in each range was selected based upon its values. Maybe this would work in Access as well?

Comment: Thank you for your replay. I actually managed to write the code in VBA in Excel, however I'm failing to get it running in Access. I don't think that this approach would work in Access.